# Proxy/cache with with download accelerator (parallel range requests)

Tags: proxy, http, cache, http-proxy

I'd like to use SuperUser collective wisdom to find an **http proxy-cache** with integrated download accelerator or in other words: parallel range requests.

The use case is: a user requests a large file, the proxy instead of opening one connection to download that file, opens multiple parallel range requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found: **Parallel module for Nginx**. It reads data from an upstream-backed nginx location by running several concurrent range requests.

https://github.com/kaltura/nginx-parallel-module